# Asp.net MVC View Textbox Returns Default Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post

I can send lat,lon, neighbors and neighborslimit variables to View.Yet, I want change neighborlimit from view. When I post View, MapViewModel's variables are 0, I have tried to `ModelState.Clear()` but there is no difference, Could you help me about it ? Thanks

**MODEL:**

```
public class MapViewModel
{
    public double lat;
    public double lon;
    public List<Point> neighbors;
    public Polygon polygon;

    public int neighborlimit;
    public double[][] polyTable;
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Map()
    {
        UserAccount user = (UserAccount)UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
        MapViewModel model = new MapViewModel() { lat = (double)user.address.latitude, lon = (double)user.address.longitude, neighbors = user.getNeighbors(), neighborlimit= (int)user.neighborsLimit };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Map(MapViewModel model)
    {
       UserAccount user = (UserAccount)UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);         
       user.neighborsLimit = model.neighborlimit;
       UserManager.Update(user);
       return View(model); 
    }
```

**VIEW:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(h => h.neighborlimit, new { @class = "form-control" })
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a property for `neighborlimit` (just a field). Change it to

```
public int neighborlimit { get; set; }
```

which will allow the `DefaultModelBinder` to set the property when you submit the form

Comment: Thanks, it works but I have another problem now, `UserManager.Update(user)` does not change value from database, I have taken an error, **An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code** Do you have idea about it?

Comment: I have no idea what you `UserManager.Update(user);` function does. You will need to ask a new question with the details, including the error message

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have the values in the form that's why when the form is posted the values doesn't exists and the ModelBinder set default values. If the security is not a problem but hidden fields for all values that you want to persist.

Something like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(h => h.lat)
    /* Now enter hidden fields for all of the properties that you want */

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.TextBoxFor(h => h.neighborlimit, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

### UPDATE

As **Stephen Muecke** said make sure that you use properties not fields

Comment: I tried but values are still 0, When I post, values are 0 which are get to View, rest are Null, it makes sense?

For example;
lat=0
lon=0
neighborlimit=0
polygon=Null 
polyTable=Null

Comment: As @Stephen Muecke said you should change it from fields to properties. I didn't saw you are using fields not properties